# Facebook Developer: Unable to Submit Game Achievement

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to Submit my game achievements, but it is giving me an error:

```
No Aggregations created for this Action Type. Please create a completed 
Aggregation populated with sample data before submitting for review.
```

An aggregation was indeed created for the action type and has been populated with sample data (i.e. actions). Those actions are the achievements that I have registered, successfully, to my application using HTTP posts. I can double verify that these achievements were registered successfully in the preview of my Game Achievement Aggregation, where there is a list of "Preview Actions" which correspond to my achievements.

However, in the end I still cannot submit this action type for approval.

Has anyone else run into issues like this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [Achievements API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/achievements/) there's no submission required, that's only needed for custom actions and objects

You should be able to just use Achievements immediately - the only caveat being that you need to categorise your app as a Game in order to request the `publish_actions` permission at the moment (this will change the the Open Graph beta APIs are launched publicly)